Can Qualtrics create a new tab in the same Google Sheet for each new survey in a series?
Let's say I want to distribute a survey following each of the 100 training events we have planned for this year, and I have one Google Sheet to collect responses from each. I know how to set up a Qualtrics workflow that adds rows to the sheet with each new response, but to the degree that it's possible, I'd like to automate or at least reduce the manual burden of the following:

Upon creating a new survey in Qualtrics (by duplicating a survey template), a new tab named for the event would be added to the Google Sheet
Upon receiving a new response, it would be added to the appropriate tab

Obviously, #1 is where I'm a little stuck. Would a Google Script be the answer?
I haven't found anything in Qualtrics support forums related to this so I haven't tried anything outside of the add-row workflow.

Perhaps you could add an event identifier in the form, so that each response row tells which event it pertains to? All responses for all events would come to the same tab in the same spreadsheet file, but you can use filters to view only one event at a time when necessary.
This "one tab for all" approach would also make it much easier to create reports by aggregating data with query() and friends.
To keep the data manageable, make sure that all surveys use the same format.

That's a good idea...I'll check with stakeholders to see if this would be agreeable. Thanks!
